# ¿Cómo indicar la ubicación al crear una clase de C++ en Visual Studio (2015)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clase

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de C++, pero por alguna razón que no entiendo, al intentar crear nuevas clases de C++ (Agregar -> Clase..), me aparece bloqueado en la ventana que me aparece asistente tanto el cuadro para elegir el nombre de esta como la ubicación donde quiero que se cree:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ni idea de cómo hacer para poder elegir la ruta donde quiero que se genere la clase, y si le sigo en el asistente con Agregar, me saca otra ventana para elegir el nombre de la clase, pero no para elegir su ubicación...

¿Alguien me puede decir cómo hacerlo?

PD: Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (del MSDN que dan para universitarios).

Comment: algo no queda claro, la imagen que muestras permite seleccionar una ubicacion, porque mencionas que no te deja definirla ? cual es esa otra ventana que mencionas que muestra cuando defines el nombre de la clase

Comment: Leandro no me deja definirla, la he subrayado ahí para destacar que me aparece bloqueada, supongo que he conseguido que no se note, pero tanto nombre como ubicación y "examinar" aparecen desactivados.

Comment: Pero es correcto que esa opcion este bloqueado, se supone que el archivo de clase se defina dentro de la estructura del proyecto, es por eso que no puedes cambiarlo. Si quieres definirlo dentro de otro luegar en el proyecto deberias realizar click derecho del mouse en el solution explorer donde quieres agregarlo y usar la opcion Add-> New Item...

Comment: Eso en mi caso no funciona lo que me dices. Si hago clic derecho sobre el explorador de soluciones, las opciones no me dejan indicar ubicación, no me aparece ni el campo desactivado de antes.

Comment: Es que no ninguna opcion para indicar la ubicacion, esta se resuelve donde realizas click en el solution explorer, la ruta es automatica no se puede cambiar y la resuelve el VS segun donde este el proyecto fisicamente. Lo que explicas es correcto como funciona

Comment: Pero por ejemplo para otras clases distintas sí me deja seleccionar ruta y nombre, como con las clases de componentes de c++, o de windows form, y el resto que aparece en la pestaña "CLR". Por eso no entiendo muy bien por qué una clase básica de C++ no me deja, pero esas otras sí.

Comment: La verdad no programo en c++, pero si en c# y nunca he visto que se pueda especificar la ruta donde crear el item. Cree en mi VS2015 un proyecto C# y añado un form nuevo, solo me deja indicarle el nombre, la ruta sale automatica y se determina de forma relativa a donde este el proyecto

Comment: En ese caso, cabe esperar si alguna otra persona puede ayudarme, porque yo creo que sí tendría sentido, se supone que puedes tener una ruta X de compilación, pero puedes tener subclases ahí dentro, o añadir directorios adicionales para compilar, entonces se debería poder indicar dónde crear la clase, pero gracias de todos modos.

Comment: no veo que tipo de ayuda esperas, lo que describes es correcto y es asi como funciona. Es mas realiza la prueba crea la clase y ubicala fisicamente donde se crea, veras que lo hace dentro de la estructura del proyecto

Comment: Quizá no me expliqué correctamente. Por ejemplo, tienes un directorio X, y en ese directorio X quieres mantener las clases organizadas por carpetas. O añades otros directorios adicionales para compilar, ¿No sería lógico poder decidir dónde se crean esas clases? Si no puedes decidirlo, como me pasa a mí, porque me aparece desactivado ese campo, entonces si creo la clase con el asistente, me la va a situar en un lugar que yo no quiero, y si la muevo luego de sitio a mano, eso me dará problemas dentro de visual studio, porque me dirá que la clase que yo tenía en X ruta ya no existe.

Comment: Pero ese directorio X esta dentro de la estructura del proyecto ? recuerda estas usando el VS y este sigue una estructura de solucion, proyecto y clases cada una debe estar contenida fisicamente, no peude ponerla donde se te antoje salvo que uses la opcion de incluir un archivo existente (pero no lo recomendaria). Puede cambiar mediante opciones donde quieres que se compile el codigo, eso lo defines en las propeidades del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Entonces se supone que para agregar una clase en un directorio concreto no existe ninguna forma de hacerlo? Dentro de la solución, lo que yo creo son directorios virtuales para organizar el código, pero esos directorios virtuales no reflejan su organización real si lo vemos desde el explorador. Si yo ahora tengo una solución casa, y dentro de VS me creo un directorio Muebles, al añadir las clases, se me van a agregar a un directorio físico general que no puedo cambiar, aunque en el IDE se vean virtualmente dentro del directorio Muebles.

Comment: claro pero a nivel de la solucion no deberias definir clases, lo correcto es  defines proyectos, recuerda hay uan estructura, Solucion -> Proyecto -> clases, puedes organizar en carpetas virtuales los proyectos, y dentro de estos definir otros directorios para definir clases. Cuando creas un directorio virtual puedes ir luego al Windows Explorer y crear la carpeta fisica con el mismo nombre para que mapee, de esta forma cuando crees el proyecto lo hara alli dentro. Si solo creas el directorio en la solucion sera virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la **extensión C++ Windows Forms**, para programar (con Forms) en C++ con VS (Visual Studio Community 2015); Al añadir una clase : **Boton derecho sobre el proyecto >> Agregar >> Clase..** . Hago clic al **botón [ Agregar ]**, entonces aparece esta **ventana en que puedo elegir el nombre de la clase, su ubicación, el nombre del archivo .cpp y otros valores de la clase**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]